# Fastest way to find matching index between two lists in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two lists as

```py
listA = ['123', '345', '678']
listB = ['ABC123', 'CDE455', 'GHK678', 'CGH345']
```

I want to find the position of listB that matched with each element in listA. For example, the expected output is

```
0 3 2
```

where `123` appears in the fist element of listB so result returns 0, `345` appears in fourth postion of listB so it is 3. Note that the number of element in two list is very huge (about 500K elements) so the `for loop` is too slow. Have you suggest any faster solution? This is my solution

```
for i in range (len(listA)):
    for j in range (len(listB)):
        if listA[i] in listB[j]:
            print ('Postion ', j)
```

Comment: Is this the actual data or are these abbreviations? In other words, if I can walk over `listB` once and make a dict of `last_3_numbers => idx` then it's a linear algorithm. But if this data is just made up and the pattern could be anything I'd have to try plan B (and hopefully you could elaborate on what the data really looks like in that eventuality).

Comment: Hi, This is random data.

Comment: All right--I recommend editing the post to explain that and hopefully post some snippets of the actual data. I can't think of a way to optimize this further without making use of some characteristics of the data itself.

Comment: Is either list *static* or are they continually changing? How many times do you have to do this operation - once, lots? Are `listA` strings always *numeric*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this. We know finding something in dictionary is fastest so the solution should use dictionary for the task completion.

```
In [1]: import re                                                                        

In [2]: listA = ['123', '345', '678']                                                    

In [3]: listB = ['ABC123', 'CDE455', 'GHK678', 'CGH345']                                 

In [4]: # Mapping b/w number in listB to related index                                   

In [5]: mapping = {re.sub(r'\D+', '', value).strip(): index for index, value in enumerate(listB)}                                                                         

In [6]: mapping # Print mapping dictionary                                               
Out[6]: {'123': 0, '455': 1, '678': 2, '345': 3}

In [7]: # Find the desired output                                                        

In [8]: output = [mapping.get(item) for item in listA]                                   

In [9]: output                                                                           
Out[9]: [0, 3, 2]

In [10]:
```

> Attached screenshot »

[image]

Comment: Please don't post images of code/data/Tracebacks.  Just copy the text, paste it in your question and format it as code.

Comment: Thank you very much @wwii. Will consider next time.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding all the elements in the list to a `set()` and searching it. It's supposed to have a much faster `in` test.

Comment: I don't believe that's an answer.

Answer (score 0):

It essentially depends on your dataset. If you're given a sufficiently large enough dataset that you require low complexity, I'd suggest looking into the [aho corasick algorithm](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/aho-corasick-algorithm-pattern-searching/). The gist of it is that you'd preprocess `listA` such that it becomes a trie whose nodes contain a failure link to the longest suffix of the current node in the trie. Because of this, you may simply iterate across each character in each word of `listB` and follow the trie you created from preprocessing. Thus your complexity adds the processing time of `listA` rather than it becoming multiplicative.

As a side note this doesn't decrease complexity in the case of a dynamic `listA`